# Get email when anyone logs in or tries to login WordPress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site that needs to make more secured. So I am trying to get the notifications via email when any attempts(fails or success not matter) made to login into my site. I have tried below the codes.

```
<?php

function wpsln_log_wp_user_login( $user_user_login, $user ) {


    $admin_email = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
    $site_info = sprintf('%1$s (%2$s)', get_bloginfo('name'), get_bloginfo('wpurl'));

    // generate email core
    $header = 'From: "'.$admin_email.'" <'.$admin_email.'>'. "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: ".get_bloginfo('charset')."\r\n";
    $email_subject = sprintf(__('Login of the user %1$s on the website %2$s', 'wpsln'), $user->user_login, $site_info);

    $body_message = sprintf(__('Hello a user has logged in on the website %1$s. Here are the details of this access:', 'wpsln'),$site_info).'<br />'."\n";
    $body_message .= sprintf(__('User email: %1$s', 'wpsln'),    $user->user_email).'<br />'."\n";

    wp_mail($admin_email, $email_subject, $body_message, $header);

}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wpsln_log_wp_user_login', '60', 2 );



function wpsln_log_wp_user_login_fail( $username ) {


    $site_info = sprintf(__('%1$s (%2$s)', 'wpsln'), get_bloginfo('name'), get_bloginfo('wpurl'));

    // generate email core
    $header = 'From: "'.$admin_email.'" <'.$admin_email.'>'. "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: ".get_bloginfo('charset')."\r\n";
    $email_subject = sprintf(__('/!\ Error : login failed on %1$s', 'wpsln'), $site_info);

    $body_message = sprintf(__('Hello, someone just failed to log in on %1$s. Here are the details:', 'wpsln'),$site_info).'<br />'."\n";
    $body_message .= sprintf(__('Login: %1$s', 'wpsln'), $username).'<br />'."\n";
    wp_mail($admin_email, $email_subject, $body_message, $header);

}
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'wpsln_log_wp_user_login_fail' );
```

But this code does not give me the notification. What are the problems I do not understand. Actually I am new in the WordPress. So please help me out.

Another ask to you. Here is the code may be for the notification to be sent to the admin email. In my site there is two more admin. My question is "to which admin email the notification email be sent?"

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying right thing, but i think you are call `wp_login` hook very late.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wpsln_log_wp_user_login', '10', 2 );
```

instead

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wpsln_log_wp_user_login', '60', 2 );
```

and your wp_login_failed works fine but you have missing

```
$admin_email = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
```

The mail will be send to administrator which is inside 
Settings->general->E-mail Address

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is working, Great. But I need one extra feature in the **wp_login_failed** hook. I want the password used by the user in attempt also to be sent if the login fails.

Comment: Hello @Shravab I am really in need to know the way to get the password when the login attempts fail. Pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Wordfence? It gives you details such as when the attempt was made, the ip address, country, and it allows you to block them as well. It also tells you who logged in and the users role. You also get a email notification every time the login fails or is successful. I usually set it to one attempt. This eliminates multiple attempts from the same ip and it blocks them from loggin in for at least 5 minutes. You can then permanently block them if you like. That's what I usually do.

I wait until they attempt to login, wordfence catches them, I see there ip addresses, then i ban them from the site.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/

Comment: Thanks u a lot for the suggestion. I am willing to use the wordfence. But I need to know how can I get the password to be sent to admin email if the ligin attempts fails. I have written some codes above. Please refer me something or codes. @galfaro

Comment: I think you're going to run into an issue retrieving the used password. The issue is that wordpress hashes each submitted password, so you wont be able to see what the used password was in the first place. To be honest a brute force attack is something you should worry about instead. I'm not sure what a list of words, or character is going to do for you. You can also harden your site so only your ip address is allowed to access the backend

Comment: I know that the original password can not be retrieved as md5 formate can not be reversed. I want that md5 or hashed formate password. If any way to retrieve that pls help me out.@galfaro